# Lists with multiline elements to iterate with foreach

Tags: line-breaking, foreach

I want to have a list of elements that may contain new lines on them. For example,

```
\def\mylist{
test,
test

with enter,
end
}
```

However, if I try to iterate over that list with `\foreach` i get a `! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@normal@list was complete.` error.

How can I declare and handle lists with multi-line elements?

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor}

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\par\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\def\mylist{
test,
test

with enter,
end
}

\foreach \x in \mylist {\test{\x}}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is

```
! Paragraph ended before \pgffor@normal@list was complete.
<to be read again> 
                   \par
```

This means that TeX has found `\par` (inserted because of the blank line) in the argument of a non `\long` macro. Indeed `\show\pgffor@normal@list` gives

```
> \pgffor@normal@list=macro:
#1->\def \pgffor@values {#1, \pgffor@stop ,}\ifx \pgffor@values \pgffor@emptyva
lues \def \pgffor@values {\pgffor@stop ,}\fi \let \pgffor@body =\pgfutil@empty 
\global \pgffor@continuetrue \pgffor@collectbody .
```

However, making this macro `\long` is not sufficient, because also `\pgffor@scanone` and `\pgffor@dots@in@` are non `\long`.

Solution: make the macros `\long`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgffor,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd[\long]{\pgffor@normal@list}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\pgffor@scanone}{}{}{}{}
\patchcmd[\long]{\pgffor@dots@in@}{}{}{}{}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\test}[1]{\par\fbox{\parbox{\linewidth}{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\def\mylist{
test,
test

with enter,
end
}

\foreach \x in \mylist {\test{\x}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are not introducing a new line, but a new *paragraph*!
Apparently, `\foreach` does not like paragraph breaks.  I did not find out why in the pgfmanual, though (which just says "Anything can be used as a value").  If you want to force a line break, you can use `\\`, which works well with `\foreach`:

```
\def\mylist{
test,
test\\ with new line,
end
}

\foreach \x in \mylist {\test{\x}}
```

In case you really need a paragraph break, you could use the following is a workaround:

```
\def\mylist{
test,
test\mypar with enter,
end
}    
\foreach \x in \mylist {\let\mypar=\par\test{\x}}
```